# Why doesn't async await work with axios correctly?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, axios

https://codesandbox.io/s/asyncawait-axios-practice-c060n

This is a link to a sandbox I have with simple code. Why does it keep returning a promise and not waiting until the it is finished resolving as I put await before the axios call?

It's as if it's just returning the promis and it's done. If I do a console.log inside the function local scope it will return a promise object and  if I return the result and do a console.log in global scope, it will return what I'm looking for. The thing is, I thought I didn't have to do it that way and wait for the promise to resolve. I get that asyn returns a promise and axios does too... so what am I missing when dealing with promises resolving promises?

```
import axios from "axios";

async function GetPosts() {
  const result = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
  const data = await result.data;
  return data;
}

const response = GetPosts();
console.log(response);
```

I just want to make sure my fundamental understanding of what's going on is correct.

- I'm importing axios
- I'm declaring an function called GetPosts() that has await before the axios call. (I'm assuming it will pause until it is finished)
- I'm awaiting for the results data

I receive a promise instead of the intended json. Why?

Comment: an `async` function always returns a Promise; that's pretty much the point. From a non-async context, you can write `GetPosts().then(response => console.log(response))`

Comment: As the answer notes, you can also call the function with `await` from inside another `async` function.

Comment: you don’t need `await result.data;`, using `await` on the previous line, when declaring `result`, ‘pauses’ program execution until `axios.get()` returns a promise, which means the value will subsequently be available to assign to a variable or return.  this is a good article on `axios.get()` and also shows example with `try/catch` block, as suggested in Dominic’s answer:  https://flaviocopes.com/axios/#get-requests

Comment: also relevant: `”Async functions always return a promise, whether you use await or not. That promise resolves with whatever the async function returns, or rejects with whatever the async function throws”`, see [developers.google article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/async-functions#async_return_values)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are calling the function but not waiting on the results.

```
(async () => {
  const response = await GetPosts();
  console.log(response);
})();
```

Without waiting all you are receiving back is a Promise.

It's worth noting that you should always expect the worst and handle request errors either in GetPosts or outside it with a `catch`.

Comment: Thank you! So it was just a fundamental misunderstanding on my part. It's literally just how promises work.I appreciate the help!